# Experimental method to determine the centre of mass for 3D object

Tags: measurements

I have to determine the centre of mass for a 3D object (bounding box: approximately $0.30 \text{ m} \times 0.20 \text{ m} \times 0.10 \text { m}$) that is not regular and does not have a uniform density. I know how to determine the centre of mass for a flat object. I thought that I could try to use a similar approach for the 3D object, but the problem that I have is that I cannot determine the intersection of the planes as it is somewhere inside the object.

Then I thought I could use a balance for three directions and determine the centre of mass by finding the point of balance for all three "main directions".

> Is the last method a good method? What is the best way to determine
>   the centre of mass by measurement?

Comment: To eliminate impractical answers, can you add what size this object is? Can you hang it with ropes? Can you tilt and weigh it?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added the dimensions. You can hang it with ropes you can also tilt and weigh it.

Comment: You give the dimensions and say it's not regular. Does this mean it is not box-shaped? In that case, are the given dimensions merely those of the object's bounding box? Do you know the general shape of the object _a priori_? If so, could you give us a sketch?

Comment: @Wasabi: Yes the measurements are the bounding box and I don't know the general shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I regularly determine the 3d centroid of UAVs (drones) in this way:

- a) Find a container with flat, orthogonal faces (a box) that contains
  the object tightly

  b) Pad the interior with tissue or styrofoam peanuts so that the
  object does not move

  c) Use a wooden dowel as a fulcrum and balance the container

  d) Mark the location of the dowel vs. the box face

  e) Repeat for the other sides

  f) the intersection of the planes marked on the container coincides
  with the mass centroid.

The mass of the container + peanuts should be small compared to the object to be measured.

Answer (score 2):

Two options, you can pick the more suitable / practical one.

1. **option 1: hanging** : you can hang the object and draw a gravitational (vertical) line or many of them. Then you hang it from another point and again draw the line(s). They coincide at the CG point. You may have to do some analysis to find metric values for the CG location.
2. **option 2: tilt and weigh** : measuring it at a certain pitch angle gives you the CG_x and CG_y, if you locate three scales on a perfect floor and place your object pressing three scales. If you measure it after tilting it (like 30 degrees) you can also find out the CG_z value.

Your method is similar to **option 2**. But I couldn't be sure whether one measurement with the suggested setup is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to pendulum the thing and calculate the pendulum arm from the swing period that corresponds to the CG. Note, there are two options here, a single pendulum where the object also rotates with the swing, or multiple suspension points of the same length where the object stays flat as it swings. As in the other methods, to get the exact cg, you need to do this at least 3 times in noncoplanar orientations and calculate the intersection. This is actually an approved method for computing the VCG of smallish boats.

Comment: An interesting method.  I imagine one would have to compensate for air-resistance slowing the swing and making the pendulum seem longer than it really is.

Comment: @Wossname your presumption is incorrect for all but the least dense objects, otherwise grandfather clocks wouldn't work.  But if you're paranoid, do the tests in a vacuum chamber.  NASA has some nice big ones.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, Grandfather clocks are calibrated to dial out that error, I don't think your analogy works.

Comment: @PhilSweet This is not an "approved" method for marine systems!  When computing the stability of a ship, the roll angles are derived after shifting known weights at a known position. Any attempt to infer stability from roll period is incorrect.